# Rendering sass template from a sinatra app doesn't work. Is this due to v.1 incompatibility? Workaround?

Tags: rendering, sinatra, sass

```
get '/stylesheets/style.css' do
  header 'Content-Type' => 'text/css; charset=utf-8'
  sass :style
end
```

does not produce the stylesheet anymore.

What would be a version 1.0 compatible way to do this? Or, troubleshooting suggestions if you think that the issue is with the code?

The style.sass file is in the /views folder. Haml files from the same folder render OK.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Got it, seems that the header line is deprecated/unnecessary and causes an error.

So, this worked

```
get '/stylesheets/style.css' do
  sass :style
end
```